mongoose not updating document using findOneAndUpdate
I'm trying to update a document in my event schema when a successful order is placed. I want to make 'isPurchased' to true so the product can no longer be purchased but when i set it it stays as false. What am i doing wrong here?
Here is the action
export const createOrder = async (order: CreateOrderParams) => {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase();

    const eventId = order.eventId

    const updatedEvent = await Event.findOneAndUpdate(
      {eventId},
     { $set: { isPurchased: true } },
     {new:true}
   )
    
    const newOrder = await Order.create({
      ...order,
      event: order.eventId,
      buyer: order.buyerId,
    });

    console.log(updatedEvent)
    
    return {
      order: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newOrder)),
      updated: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updatedEvent))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
}

here is the schema for the 'Event' model
import { Document, Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

export interface IEvent extends Document {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  seatInfo: string;
  location: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  startDateTime: Date;
  ticketUrl:string;
  price: string;
  quantity: string;
  seller: { _id: string, firstName: string, lastName: string };
  isPurchased:boolean;
}

const EventSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  seatInfo: { type: String },
  location: { type: String },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  startDateTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  ticketUrl: {type: String },
  price: { type: String },
  quantity: {type: String },
  seller: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  isPurchased: {type:Boolean, default:false}
})

const Event = models.Event || model('Event', EventSchema);

export default Event;

finally here are the params used in the action
export type CreateOrderParams = {
  stripeId: string
  eventId: string
  buyerId: string
  totalAmount: string
  createdAt: Date
}

I tried the findOneAndUpdate as well as findByIdAndUpdate but it is not changing isPurchased to true. It is only creating the order which is fine, and creating the order in the MongoDB Database.

Print the eventId before the update operation to ensure it matches an existing document's _id. You should be adding additional error handling to assist better.

Also, check for data type consistency. One of the common mistakes is mismatching strings with ObjectIds. This will result in failure in finding the document and updating it.

hmmm weird, none of my console logs are printing

Either there is no document for the given eventId, or there is an error thrown. Please try to include a console.log(error) in the catch block temporarily commenting handleError call.

firstly check that your id is correct or not and then if you only want to change one field you can use this:
const locator = {_id:eventId}
const updatedEvent = await Event.findOneandUpdate(locator, { isPurchased: true },{new:true})

this will update the document if the locator is correct you can check that by:
let testing = await Event.findOne(locator)

if the object returned locator is correct
